# Regex to match a sentence and word of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want to make a regex which can to match a sentence and word of matches sentence. 
      **If '!', '?' , '.' is matched then it treats as end of the sentence and it also matches each and every words of a matched sentence.**

My regex to match sentence: `[^?!.]+`

My regex to match each and every word separately: `[^\s]+`

But, I can't to join this two regex to do that.

*...Tested string...*

```
I am Raktim Banerjee. I love to code.
```

should return

```
2 sentence 8 words
```

And

```
 Stackoverflow is the best coding forum. I love stackoverflow!
```

should return

```
2 sentence 9 words.
```

Thanks in advance for your helping hand.

Comment: dot can appear within a sentence as well for acronyms and for suffices like `jr, Mr` etc

Comment: Don't try to do everything at once. Just match the sentences, then `forEach` sentence, split it into words.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I already give my two tried regexp one is for matches sentence and another for words.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, it right there are many way to do the same thing. But I want to learn regex. that's why...

Comment: @anubhava yes, it is another problem. Even if I write an e-mail address then '.' also treat as end of the string. I marked this point.

Comment: @anubhava this regex ` /[^.!\s]+(?=[^.!]*[.!])/g` only match word. But not a sentence. **I want that is match words as well as sentence.**

Comment: @RAKTIMBANERJEE `\b\w+(?:['\w-.])*\b` to count words and `[?!.](?= |$)` to count sentences

Comment: @RAKTIMBANERJEE you also can't count in regex, so this needs to remain two separate patterns - the counting is done in the programming language you're using (usually just the count/length property of the result array).

Comment: I suggest that you split the input string on sentences and then count the words per sentence and add that to the total.

Comment: @ctwheels  some finally I understand that I can't do it on a single regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you said you wanted this in JavaScript:

```js
var s = 'I am Raktim Banerjee. I love to code.'

var regex = /\b([^!?. ]+)(?:(?: +)([^!?. ]+))*\b([!?.])/g
var m, numSentences = 0, numWords = 0;
do {
    m = regex.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        numSentences++;
        numWords += m[0].split(' ').length
    }
} while (m);
console.log(numSentences + ' sentences, ' + numWords + ' words')
```

Here is a second iteration. I modified the regex to recognize a few salutations, Mr., Mrs. and Dr. (you can add additional ones), and to add a primitive sub regular expression to recognize an email address. And I also simplified the original regex a bit. I hope this helps (no guarantees because the email check is overly simplified):

```js
var s = 'Mr. Raktim Banerjee. My email address is x.y.z@nowhere.com.'

var regex = /\b((Mrs?\.|Dr\.|\S+@\S+|[^!?. ]+)\s*)+([!?.])/g
var m, numSentences = 0, numWords = 0;
do {
    m = regex.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        numSentences++;
        numWords += m[0].split(' ').length
    }
} while (m);
console.log(numSentences + ' sentences, ' + numWords + ' words')
```

Comment: Yes, I exactly want like that, But the problem is when '.' came inside a sentence. Like **Mr. Raktim Banerjee**. should return **2 sentences 3 words**. But, it is **actually 1 sentences and 3 words**.  This problem is also arise when I enter any e-mail address because email address  carry '.' **example@abc.com**

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
import re
s1="I am Raktim Banerjee. I love to code. "
s2="Stackoverflow is the best coding forum. I love stackoverflow! "

print(len(re.compile("[^?!.]+").findall(s1))-1,"sentence",len(re.compile("[^\s]+").findall(s1)),"words")

print(len(re.compile("[^?!.]+").findall(s2))-1,"sentence",len(re.compile("[^\s]+").findall(s2)),"words")
```

Running above outputs:

```
2 sentence 8 words
2 sentence 9 words
```

Comment: Yah, I want like this, output is as my expectations. But I can not understand the code.

Comment: Great! "findall" will match all the patterns and "len" will count the no. of matches. Since the last (. or ! or ? ) will create an extra split hence have to do -1 for sentence count. And word count is as it is, as you mentioned in your regex.

Comment: Sir, what is mean by `import re` ?

Comment: this is for importing regex package.

Comment: Okay. But this is on python. I want to do it on JS.

Comment: You can build on this logic.

Comment: Yes, I will try it.